# vb.net how to check if a network drive is mapped persistently

Tags: vb.net, mapped-drive, persistent-connection

I use the following code to layout network drives on a system. I want to add a third column for persistence but in vb.net I do not know how to check if a drive has a persistent map or not. Any suggestions?

```
For Each drive_info As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        If drive_info.DriveType().ToString = "Network" Then
            With maps.Items.Add(drive_info.Name)
                .SubItems.Add(drive_info.DriveType().ToString)
            End With
        End If
    Next drive_info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have always done it in WMI without any (well okay fewer) nasty cludges.

e.g.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management

Public Module modmain
   Sub Main()
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkConnection WHERE LocalName = 'Z:'")
    Dim obj As ManagementObject
    For Each obj In searcher.Get
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", obj.Item("LocalName").ToString, obj.Item("Persistent"))
    Next
   End Sub
End Module
```

Obviously you need to add a reference to System.Management.dll and change Z: to the drive you are checking, or you could probably replace all your code with just that snippet as removing the WHERE clause will return all mapped drives.

Comment: This does what I'm looking for, thanks. It also gives me the option to add more data in my list using the win32_NetworkConnection class, which I'm reading up on right now.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.  It is a C# class that enumerates network resources, and has the ability to distinguish persistent connections:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csenumnetworkresources.aspx?msg=964694

I apologize that it is in C#, but it does some things like marshaling memory that I don't know how to do in VB.

Constants are passed to the `EnumerateServers` function to provide fine control of the output. The constant you would find of interest is:

```
RESOURCE_REMEMBERED
```

*Enumerates remembered (persistent) connections.*