# vb.net how to check network drive is mapped

Tags: vb.net, websocket, network-drive

I am studying VB.NET and looking for way to check if application mapped to network drive.
I check
[vb.net how to check if a network drive is mapped persistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585976/vb-net-how-to-check-if-a-network-drive-is-mapped-persistently)

and i also trying to ping to network drive. However, this method seem not workinng.

I  was trying ping to  network drive  and it was always return false.

I made function.
On the function part

```
    Public Function CheckForInternetConnection(path As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Using client = New WebClient()

                Using stream = client.OpenRead(path)
                    Return True
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

On the running part i call this function above

```
CheckForInternetConnection("google.com")
CheckForInternetConnection("\\mynetowrk_Driver.com\system\application")
```

When i use CheckForInternetConnection with "google.com" it return "TRUE"
However, when i use "\mynetowrk_Driver.com\system\application"  this network drive, it return **FALSE**

I am not sure how i can check if netowork driver was mapped .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to validate two different things. See if the code below helps you:

```
Public Function CheckForInternetConnection(path As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Return My.Computer.Network.Ping(path)
    Catch pingException As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException
        Return IO.Directory.Exists(path)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```